# How to access tabBarController from AppDelegate.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode5

This is my storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

I am trying to access tabBarController from a method inside AppDelegate.m

This is AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "STAlertView.h"


@interface demo_AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) STAlertView *av;

@end
```

And this is AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "demo_AppDelegate.h"
#import "demo_Friends_ViewController.h"


@implementation demo_AppDelegate
-(void)showFriendReqAlert:(NSNotification *)pNotification{
    NSLog(@"Hello from showFriendReqAlert:");
    NSLog(@"Root: %@", [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.tabBarController viewControllers]);

}
....
....
....
....
@end
```

My main motive is when this method `showFriendReqAlert:` is called, a red badge is shown to the third tab bar item which is `Friends`. But whenever i try to select tabBarItem, it says null in NSLog.

I have also tried the following:
self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.tabBarController
self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController

but nothing works. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the navigation controller between your login screen and the tab bar? What kind of segue are you using from login? Your login screen is not embedded in a navigation controller so I would expect self.window.rootViewController.navigationController to be nil.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. RootViewController is the login screen and I wanna change the badge after receiving notification. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 8):

I believe (sorry for believing here ;-) that the `TabBarController` should be your first controller and your `navigationBarController` must come afterwards as it does not make much sense for the navigationController (if you change a tab) what to push/pop.

I suggest that you remove your first `DemoViewController` and following `NavigationController` and that your first Controller is your `TabBarController` (simply set "Is Initial View Controller" in IB).

Then you can access your `tabBar` like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
}
```

**Swift 5:**

```swift
guard let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the first `DemoViewController` is the one with the Login Screen. So, it must have to be there.

Comment: Okay. Are you trying to access your tabBar from your Login Screen? It might not have been loaded until you see it.

Comment: no, not from the login screen, i am actually trying to change the tab bar item after a background fetch. So, i am doing it from inside the AppDelegate.m

Comment: Have you tried to check what variable is nil: UINavigationController* nav = self.window.rootViewController.navigationController; if nav != nil { UITabBarController* tbc = nav.tabBarController; ... } Is it really the tabBarController?